# Update Python to 3.8 and the modules doesn't work

Tags: python, scipy

I had Python3.5.2 installed on /usr/bin/.
All the modules include scipy and numpy works well.

But, after I installed Python3.8 the modules scipy and numpy doesn't work.
I saw that Python3.8 is in usr/local/bin instead usr/bin.

So, how can I run Python3.8 using all the modules like I used with Python3.5.2?

Comment: Have you install the modules under the new python3.8?

Comment: No. I have to install all the modules for the new version 3.8?

Comment: Do you want to keep the 3.5 version?

Comment: No, I want to use just the version 3.8.

Comment: Yes. The 3rd party packages are usually installed in the python site_packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3.8.0 was just released on 2019-10-14, so several modules are not yet supported (as of 2019-10-31). SciPy, Matplotlib, and SciKit-Learn are not yet supported. These may be supported by the time 3.8.1 is released in 2019-12-16.

Numpy and Pandas are supported, but for the others you will need to continue using a supported version of Python. To keep both versions on your machine, I would recommend using a [virtual environment.](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)